# Bootstrap animation doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, animation, twitter-bootstrap-4

You can find bootstrap animations [here](https://mdbootstrap.com/css/animations/). I want to remove the animation after it finished. On the website you can find a trigger which should help with that.
The problem is, that when I click the button, the classes get deleted immediately.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="foo(this)">Press here</button>
<script>
function foo(element){
    $(element).addClass("animated shake");
    $(element).on('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', $(element).removeClass("animated shake"));
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Have you included the `mdbootstrap.js` on your site?

Comment: I used [this](https://github.com/modularcode/modular-admin-html) template. Without the listener the animation works. So I think the creator of the template already included that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a Timeout for the duration of your animation, to wait until the animaton is finished:

```
function foo(element){
    $(element).addClass("animated shake");
    var duration = $(element).css("animation-duration"); 
    setTimeout(function() { 
        $(element).removeClass("animated shake"); 
    }, duration);
}
```

Comment: That works nice! But I have to search or try for the time the animation needs to finish. Is there any way to use the listener they provided?

Comment: I think you can get the animation time with the `animation-duration` css style. I added this to my answer.